# Вопрос про listview в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Как переносить текст по словам? `\n` не подходит. Необходимо чтобы это происходило автоматически, если не будет хватать места.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, разделить ширину текстового виджета на размер шрифта.А дальше, расставить \n по тексту.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение я думаю есть в моем вопросе.  [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422599/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-python-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd). Также можете воспользоваться таким способом переноса текста по указанному количеству символов, где 32 в строчке `if letter_index % 32 == 0 and letter_index != 0:` обозначают количество символов после которых нужен перенос.

```
    def parse_string(message) -> str:
        message_new_line = ''
        for letter_index in range(len(message)):

            if letter_index % 32 == 0 and letter_index != 0:
                message_new_line += f'{message[letter_index]}\n'
            else:
                message_new_line += message[letter_index]
        return message_new_line
```

Там такое же условие по автоматическому переносу текста

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).