# Автоматический перенос текста на новую строку Python (Вопрос решен)

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, перенос-слов

**Приветствую!**
Стояла задача, полученный текст от пользователя переносить на новую строку через каждые 33 символа. Сам перенос текста я решил следующим образом:

```
def parse_string(string: str) -> str:
    new_string = ""

    for letter_index in range(len(string)):

        if letter_index % 33 == 0 and letter_index != 0:
            new_string += "\n"
        else:
            new_string += string[letter_index]

    return new_string


print(parse_string("«Чудесный доктор» — трогательный святочный рассказ Куприна. Двое мальчиков из обнищавшей семьи Мерцаловых возвращаются с нарядных, готовящихся к празднику улиц домой в подвал, где их ждет мать, больная сестра и голодный младенец"))
```

**Проблема:**
**При переносе текста, функция убирает символ в месте переноса из слова.**
Где я допустил ошибку?

*Вывод в консоль:*

```
«Чудесный доктор» — трогательный 
вяточный рассказ Куприна. Двое м
льчиков из обнищавшей семьи Мерц
ловых возвращаются с нарядных, г
товящихся к празднику улиц домой
в подвал, где их ждет мать, боль
ая сестра и голодный младенец
```

> Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

**Решение**

Нужно было добавить в строку `new_string += "\n"`
следующие изменения `new_string += f"{string[letter_index]}\n"`

> Спасибо @Namerek за помощь!

Comment: Немного офтоп, но все-же. https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-textwrap-python/klass-textwrapper-modulja-textwrap/

Comment: И вот здесь посмотрите, возможно будет для Вас интересно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086822/how-to-justify-text-right-alignment-in-python

Comment: Что касается Вашего кода то `new_string += f"{string[letter_index]}\n"` вместо `new_string += "\n"`

Comment: @Namerek Спасибо! ваше решение помогло разобраться. Также спасибо за приведенную выше информацию, обязательно ею воспользуюсь в следующий раз, она достаточно полезна!

Comment: Ещё изучите функцию `enumerate`, она тут как-раз бы пригодилась, код был бы чуть проще и понятнее.

Comment: @CrazyElf  Спасибо, ознакомлюсь